# Redirecting input from a file with youtube-dl

Tags: redirect, youtube-dl

I am trying to redirect input from a file in which some youtube links are stored, I am using given below command to download those videos..

```
youtube-dl < link_file.txt
```

but above command gives an error..

```
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can probably use `xargs` - the details will depends on what format the URLs are in your file, and whether `youtube-dl` can accept multiple URLs in a single invocation: I'd *guess* `< link_file.txt xargs -L1 youtube_dl`

Comment: what is `< link_file.txt xargs -L1 youtube_dl` this ? I tried `youtube-dl < link_file.txt xargs -L1`, but it is not working,  please tell me full command (whaterver you want to say)

Comment: `youtube-dl -a links_file.txt` works?